# "How to make my program read visible characters and spaces from a file

Tags: c

I am supposed to be "fixing" code given to me to make it display the correct number of visible characters in a file (spaces too). The correct number is supposed to be 977. I have never dealt with files before and I don't understand what I need to do to display the correct number.

```
 * Driver Menu System for Homework
 * Andrew Potter - Mar 5, 2019  <-- Please put your name/date here
 */

#include <stdio.h>//header file for input/output -
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
// since you will place all your assigned functions (programs) in this file, you do not need to include stdio.h again!

int menu(void);   //prototype definition section
void hello(void);
void countall(void);

int main(void)
{
    int selection = menu();

    while(selection != 99) {

        switch(selection) {

        case 1:
           hello();
           break;

        case 2:
            countall();
           break;

        case 3:

           break;

        case 4:

           break;

         default:
            printf("Please enter a valid selection.\n");
        }

    selection = menu();
    }

   return 0;
}

int menu(void) {
    int choice;
    printf("***************************\n");
    printf(" 1. Hello \n");
    printf(" 2. Countall\n");
    printf(" 3. \n");
    printf(" 4. \n");
    printf("99. Exit\n");
    printf("Please select number and press enter:\n");
    printf("***************************\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    getchar();
    return choice;
}

void hello(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!!!\n");
}

//*****Andrew 5/1/19*****

#define SLEN 81    /* from reverse.c */
/* original header: int count(argc, *argv[]) */
void countall(void)
{
    int ch;         // place to store each character as read
    FILE *fp;       // "file pointer"
    long unsigned count = 0;
    char file[SLEN];  /* from reverse.c */

    /*Checks whether a file name was included when run from the command prompt
     * The argument count includes the program file name. A count of 2 indicates
     * that an additional parameter was passed
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
     * The following uses the second parameter as the file name
     * and attempts to open the file
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } */

    /*************************************
     Code from reverse.c included to make the program work from within our IDE
     *************************************/
    puts("Enter the name of the file to be processed:");
    scanf("%s", file);

    if ((fp = fopen(file,"rb")) == NULL)   /* read mode */
    {
        printf("count program can't open %s\n", file);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* EOF reached when C realizes it tried to reach beyond the end of the file! */
    /* This is good design - see page 573  */
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
      if (isprint(ch)) {
          count++;
} 
      else if (isprint(ch)) {
        count++;
} 
        putc(ch,stdout);  // same as putchar(ch);
        count++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nFile %s has %lu characters\n", file, count);
}
```

I expected I would get the correct number of visible characters using the combination of isprint and isspace but I usually get 2086. 
The assignment directions are: "Word identifies 977 characters including spaces. Your current countall() believes there are 1043. Make the corrections necessary to your code to count only the visible characters and spaces! (Hint: check out 567 in your textbook.)" Before I edited any code the count was 1043, now i am getting 2020. I need 977.

Comment: I would suggest you research the `isprint` and `isspace` functions and re-write the code from scratch, since you will understand it better.

Comment: `if (isprint(ch) != '\n' || '\t' || '\0')` is always true.

Comment: Why do you count again after `putc()`?

Comment: What is the actual file length?  I am guessing  `2086 == (2 * file_length) - number_of_spaces`.  An explanation at the end of by answer.

Comment: Should new lines (`'\n'`) be counted?

Comment: Your code fragment is a little too terse.  It would be useful to see how you are reading `ch` and how you have opened the file.  Both can have a bearing on the result.

Comment: I have included my entire assignment now.

Comment: @Potter Indeed, but you have also _changed_ the code you originally posted, rendering content in existing answers nonsense.  Since helpful users expended significant effort in explaining the issues with the original code, you should not change the question in that way.  As mentioned in my answer, you should not open the _text_ file in _binary_ mode.  If you are counting newlines as "space" then you will count both the CR and LF for text files with Windows line end convention.

Comment: You should post the code that resulted in 1043, 2920 and 2020 characters if you choose to mention them in the question. Otherwise it is useless information.  You have gone from too selective to too much with your code presentation.  Perhaps just the countall() implementations would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isprint()` returns a Boolean result - zero if the character is not "printable", and non-zero if it is.  As such `isprint(ch) != '\n'`makes no sense. Your complete expression in the question makes even less sense, but I'll come on to that at the end.

`isprint()` on its own returns true (non-zero) for all printable characters, so you need no other tests.  Moreover you increment `count` unconditionally and in every conditional block, so you are counting every character and some twice.

You just need:

```
if( isprint(ch) )
{ 
    count++; 
}
putc( ch, stdout ) ;
```

While your code is clearly an incomplete fragment, it is not clear where or how your are reading `ch`.  You need a `getc()` or equivalent in there somewhare.

```
while( (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF ) 
{
    if( isprint(ch) )
    { 
        count++; 
    }
    putc( ch, stdout ) ;
}
```

It is not clear whether you need to count all whitespace (including space, tab and newline) or just "spaces" as you stated.  If so be clear that `isprint()` will match space, but not control characters newline or tab.  `isspace()` matches all these, but should not be counted separately to `isprint()` because 'space' is in both white-space and printable sets.  If newline and tab are to be counted (and less likely; "vertical tab") then:

```
while( (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF ) 
{
    if( isprint(ch) || isspace(ch) )
    { 
        count++; 
    }

    putc( ch, stdout ) ;
}
```

Another aspect of C that you seem to misunderstand is how Boolean expressions work.  To test a single variable for multiple values you must write:

```
if( var == x || var == y || var == z )
```

You have written:

```
if( var == x || y || z )
```

which may make sense in English (or other natural language) when you read it out aloud, but in C it means:

```
if( var == (x || y || z ) )
```

evaluating `(x || y || z )` as either `true` or `false` and comparing it to `var`.

It is probably worth considering the semantics of your existing solution to show why it actually compiles, but produces the erroneous result it does.

Firstly,

```
  isprint(ch) != '\n' || '\t' || '\0'
```

is equivalent to `isprint(ch) != true`, for the reasons described earlier. So you increment the counter for *all* characters that are *not* printable.

Then here:

```
  isspace(ch) == NULL
```

`NULL` is a macro representing an invalid pointer, and `isspace()` does not return a pointer.  However `NULL` will implicitly cast to zero (or false).  So here you increment the counter for *all* printable characters that are *not* spaces.

Finally, you *unconditionally* count every character here:

```
    putc(ch,stdout);  // same as putchar(ch);
    count++;
```

So your result will be:

```
number-of-non-printing-characters + 
number-of-printing-characters - number-of-spaces +
total-number-of-characters
```

which is I think `(2 x file-length) - number-of-spaces`

Finally note that if you open a text file that has CR+LF line ends (conventional for text files on Windows) in "binary" mode, `isspace()` will count two characters for every new-line.  Be sure to open in "text" mode (regardless of the platform).

Answer (score 1):

From [`isprint()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isprint/):

> A printable character is a character that occupies a printing position on a display (this is the opposite of a control character, checked with iscntrl).

and

> A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is a printable character. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

So that function should be sufficient. Please note that you have to make sure to feed all these `is...()` functions from `<ctype.h>` unsigned values. So if you use it with a value of uncertain origin, better cast to `char unsigned`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!input) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading. :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    long long unsigned count = 0;   
    for (int ch;  (ch = fgetc(input)) != EOF;) {
        if (isprint(ch))
            ++count;
    }

    fclose(input);
    printf("Count: %llu\n\n", count);
}
```

If I wasn't lucky enough to guess which characters you want to be counted, have a look at [`ctype.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/), there is a table.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito It takes an `int` because it can `EOF`. [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)
§7.4/1: *The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, **the value of which shall be
representable as an unsigned char** or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. **If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.***

Comment: @Swordfish : true, but in this case the `int` comes from a function that also only produces a value "_representable as an unsigned char_" or EOF, so is already compatible with ctype functions/macros without casting.  I would not be so emphatic as Frito and say you shouldn't cast, but you certainly need not in this case.

Comment: @Clifford *but you certainly need not in this case* – true that. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((ch == '\t') || isprint(ch))
        count++;
```

If you want to handle tabs differently (maybe to count how many spaces they use):

```
if (ch == '\t') {
        /* Do smth */
} else if (isprint(ch)) {
        count++;
}
```

This should be enough.

Comment: well this lowered the character count to 2020, but thats still too high.

Comment: @Potter You have `count++;` after `putc()`; what do you expect from that?

Comment: It is not clear either whether newlines should be counted.